# Why 09 or 009 and 08 or 008 isn't equal to 8 and 9?

Tags: python, int, radix

I did some simple basic operations in Python 2.7 using > , < and == comparison operators .

Then I stumbled on these dilemma :

```
9 = 09
False

9 = 009
False

8 = 08
False

8 = 008
False
```

But others are okay like :

```
1 = 01
True

1 = 001
True
```

from 1 to 7 it's okay .... :-(

Comment: Prefixing a number with a 0 means you want it to be in base-8 instead of base-10.

Comment: Thanks :-)))))))

Comment: Also `==` is the comparison operator. `=` is for assignments.

Comment: Oh im sorry . Yeah it's == . :-)

Comment: @KlausD. Didn't even notice that. Clojure's making me blind to that mistake!